# What would you call someone who plays hero in situations?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:
You have a costumer you have been working with who purchases something then your coworker later says they purchased because of something they did (like discrediting you).

Or another example would be, they are asked a simple question and then make it seem that the person who asked the question was freaking out and that they calmed them down even though the person was not freaking out at all?

I thought self righteous may be right but now I am not sure.